# Parsing specific parts of output

Tags: bash

Basically, I have this script that updates wifi firmware on jailbroken devices (iOS). I need to check the output of this:

```
/usr/libexec/wifiFirmwareLoader -f
```

This outputs me the file path to the correct files needed for the rest of the script, but I don't want the whole path, I only want the name of the file at the end of the path. How could I go about parsing this?

If you need an example, this is what the output looks like.

```
RESOLVED /usr/share/firmware/wifi/C748383-A3/hans.trx
```

I would only want to store `hans.trx` in a variable.

Comment: But what did you try to solve this problem of yours? Post your research efforts into the question even if they are trivial

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show your best attempt at  code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexes in grep:

```
echo "RESOLVED /usr/share/firmware/wifi/C748383-A3/hans.trx" | grep -Eo "[^/]+$"
```

- -E uses extended regexes. You could also use -P for perl regexes
- -o only shows the matched output
- [^/] matches everything that is not a /, the + makes it at least 1 character and the $ requires it to be at the end of the line
- If this matches more lines that you would need, you could use postive lookahead `(?=something)` or positive lookbehind `something\K` to make the regex more strict (will need -P). Or in some cases I like to double grep (first grep for lines containing something, then get the part from the line you want)

Your final script could look something like this:

```
OUTPUT=$(/usr/libexec/wifiFirmwareLoader -f)
FILENAMES=$(echo "${OUTPUT}" | grep -Eo "[^/]+$")
echo "${FILENAMES}"
```